# Linking a .cpp file to a .c file within the same directory

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, linker

I'm a beginner working on a software project in C using Eclipse.
We have numerous header and source files in the directory of the project (which is in the Eclipse workspace). Most of them are .c files, though some are .cpp.

I encounter a problem while trying to use, in a .cpp file, functions which are defined in a .c file. Usually adding the line "#include filename.h" allows usage of functions defined in filename.c, where both those files are in the same folder as the current one. This time, however, the current file is .cpp and Eclipse throws an "Unidentified reference" error (I am using an extern "C" block).
I've understood from similar Q&As that it's a linker problem, yet none of those referred to the simple case in which all files are in the same folder.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Code:

// SPFeatureExtract.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" {
#include "SPConfig.h"
}

foo() {
    ...
    numOfImages = spConfigGetNumOfImages(config, msg); // *Unidentified reference error
}
```

// SPConfig.c

```
int spConfigGetNumOfImages(const SPConfig config, SP_CONFIG_MSG* msg) {
    [implementation]
}
```

// SPConfig.h

```
int spConfigGetNumOfImages(const SPConfig config, SP_CONFIG_MSG* msg);
```

Error message:

```
E:\SoftProj\WorkSpace\Final\Debug/../SPFeatureExtract.cpp:58: undefined reference to `spConfigGetNumOfImages(sp_config_t*, sp_config_msg_t*)'
```

Comment: c++ and c is not the same thing at all

Comment: @phil652: Yes, the OP understands that - he has C code and C++ code and he wants to call between them.  This should be easy.

Comment: @phil652 I think OP knows that.

Comment: Can you show the code where the error occurs, or where you include the C functions within the .cpp file?

Comment: Can you show us the actual text of the error message, and include the header file in your question please?

Comment: Is it an error from the compiler or from the IDE? Is the header file really found and included? Check with a simple macro constant which you should be able to use regardless of the configuration / issues of the linker.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put a reference to it in Makefile?

Comment: An explanation might be that you accidentally compiled that C file in C++ mode.

Comment: @Mirakurun I don't have a Makefile (using Windows)

Comment: As a follow-up to my last comment, can you share how you compile both the SPConfig.c and SPFeatureExtract.cpp files?